# How to split the framework into its own component using composer?

Tags: git, project-management, git-subtree

How do I create a sub-package out of the main framework package? Laravel does similar with `laravel/laravel` being the skeleton application and `laravel/framework` being the root framework package. Symfony does something similar with `symfony/framework-standard-edition` to multiple components.

I just want to create some packages under my main package. Something like this:

```
Xyx
Xyz\Service
Xyz\Service\Providers\
```

The `Xyz/Service/Providers/` folder should be replaced by the specified package (example: `Abc/Service/StrProvider`) content.

Comment: You might want to check out the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) for Composer. Also, if you're using git, you might want to look into `git subtree`.

Answer (score 3):

These are git subtree splits. GitHub has a [doc article](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) about it. In short:

```
# clone your main repo
$ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
$ cd REPOSITORY-NAME

# do the actual subtree split
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME 

# push to the subtree split repo
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
$ git push -u origin BRANCH-NAME
```

---

SensioLabs, the company behind Symfony, has open sourced their go script used by Symfony as [split.sh lite](https://github.com/splitsh/lite).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am able to create a subtree using git split command but not working as expected. Also tried Splitsh but no luck. Can you please help me with this ? @Wouter

Answer (score 2):

### 2019 update!

After many years of using bash/git commands from CLI, I made a simple PHP wrapper [MonorepoBuilder](https://github.com/symplify/monorepobuilder) to make use for all developers very simple.

### 1. Prepare config

```
# monorepo-builder.yaml
parameters:
    directories_to_repositories:
        packages/CodingStandard: 'git@github.com:Symplify/CodingStandard.git'
        packages/EasyCodingStandard: 'git@github.com:Symplify/EasyCodingStandard.git'
```

### 2. Run Command

```
vendor/bin/monorepo-builder split
```

That's all!

You can read more about this [Create, Merge and Split Monorepo with 1 Command](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/10/08/new-in-symplify-5-create-merge-and-split-monorepo-with-1-command/)